# Random product selection using Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I have to performance test an e-commerce web-application using Jmeter.
One flow is like `Search > select any product > Add to Cart`.
Here I have to select any random product from the search results and proceed.

Can you please guide me on how to select any random product and proceed?
I am using Jmeter 2.11.

Comment: @Philip Allgaier Can you answer this question please? I want to use a Regular expression extractor but not knowing how to extract and randomize the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below sequence,

(If you know how many products are there then)

```
1. add random variable with values 1-no. of products. this will generate random values for each user/iteration
2. use values from random variable (var1) in regular expression extractor for random occurance (var1 occurance which is random every time)
```

(If you dont know how many products are present and if your response contains no. of products count then)

```
1. In first regular expression extract count of products in a variable 
2. add random variable with values 1-value for first regex. this will generate random values for each user/iteration
3. use values from random variable (var1) in regular expression extractor for random occurance
```

I have used similar technique in my assgn. attaching snapshots for reference.

Random selector

[image: Random Selector]

first regex for count

[image: First regex for count]

random variable

[image: random variable]

2nd regex for random oocurance

[image: random occurance]

you can modify regex as per your requirement.

Comment: please upvote/accept if it was helpful and if you think I deserve :)