# How to capture thread specific different data form drop down list in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

My application consist the Select Title drop down list contains values as Mr, Miss, Dr & Mrs.

I want to capture the different title (Random but from above 4) for different thread. please suggest how it is possible.

This is my script i have pass the title parameter as ${randomTitle}

[image]

Value pass to database as,
[image]

Post request as,
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest, is it vital to use enum there?

Try amending your code as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

String[] frm_titles = {"Mr", "Miss", "Dr", "Mrs"};
Random randGenerator = new Random();
int randInt = randGenerator.nextInt(frm_titles.length);
vars.put("randomTitle",frm_titles[randInt]);
```

It should work this way. Enum must not be local to Beanshell interpreter, if you need to use enum structure - compile it as .jar and place it to JMeter classpath.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beanshell Preprocessor:

```
import java.util.Random;

public enum frm_titles {"Mr", "Miss", "Dr", "Mrs"};
Random randGenerator = new Random();
int randInt = randGenerator.nextInt(frm_titles.values().length);
vars.put("randomTitle",frm_titles.values()[randInt].toString());
```

Then, in your test plan change the post params and add `${randomTitle}` instead your title param.

Check this links for more info:

http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

http://testeverythingqtp.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/jmeter-bean-shell-script-create-file.html

http://jmeter-kh.blogspot.com.es/2009/07/how-to-make-beanshell-work-in-jmeter.html

Comment: just like this "&#x24;&#x7b;randomTitle&#x7d;" data passed, i can't understand where i am wronge.

Comment: error as, 014/06/16 15:44:04 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Random;  enum titles {Mr, Miss, Dr, Mrs}; Random randGenerator  . . . '' Encountered "enum" at line 3, column 1.
 
2014/06/16 15:44:04 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.Random;  enum titles {Mr, Miss, Dr, Mrs}; Random randGenerator  . . . '' Encountered "enum" at line 3, column 1.

Comment: still data pass as "&#x24;&#x7b;randomTitle&#x7d;".

Comment: `${randomTitle}` should be in your post variable, show the post requests please

Comment: question edited as per req. hi Sal00m, is there any environment related setting required for this? i.e. setting the path or else.

Comment: String[] frm_titles = {"Mr", "Miss", "Dr", "Mrs"}; this works for me, thanks for your valuable efforts.

Answer (score -1):

I think 2 ways are possible,

1. you can try beanshell processor
2. you can try regular expression extractor and counter

first approach is best explained above, for 2nd approach you can try,

[Random product selection using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366723/random-product-selection-using-jmeter/22375601#22375601)

Comment: but in above i.e. 1st approach, dropdown data pass as "&#x24;&#x7b;randomTitle&#x7d;" which is incorrect, please guide.

Comment: frankly speaking, I like 2nd approach, its manageable and every time works. yes it is bit time taking to create but easy to create.

Comment: can you more ex-plane the 2nd approach or any help so i can go to systematic fashion.

Comment: I dont think this was worth of -1 :(. See generally in response, count of values in dropdown is present if no fancy code is written. from there you can extract the count and feed it as upper bound to random variable which generates random nos from 1-count which can be used for selecting random values from drop down list

Comment: frankly i know both the techniques works but you can't go for any one. i am expected any one technique in details. in my case its simple drop down & i know the data.