# Drop down list correlation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can any one help me on Drop downlist correlation in JMeter?

I Have a scenario to select City names from dropdown list, During execution i would like to pass randomly one value on each iteration. (I aware in Loadrunner as we can achieve it using lr_paramarr_random  methods). How to store and pass randomly to the script ?

Ex: City_ddl - (Length is 5) 
    Hyderabd
    Banglore
    Chennai
    Pune
    Delhi

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237895/how-to-capture-thread-specific-different-data-form-drop-down-list-in-jmeter

Answer (score 1):

1. There is [__chooseRandom()](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup) function available via JMeter Plugins. Using it is as simple as below:

   ```
   ${__chooseRandom(Hyderabad,Bangalore,Chennai,Pune,Delhi,randomCity)}
   ```
2. If you're getting dropdown values via [XPath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor), they are stored in JMeter Variables like:

   ```
   CITY_1=Delhi
   CITY_2=Pune
   CITY_3=Chennai
   ..etc. 
   CITY_matchNr=5
   ```

   In that case you should be able to choose random value without JMeter custom functions plugin using just [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) and [__V](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) built-in functions as follows:

   ```
   ${__V(CITY_${__Random(1,${CITY_matchNr},)})}
   ```

For more details on using JMeter's functions refer to [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series.