# How can we pass random values from the selected values in jMeter?

Tags: random, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to pass some parameters to my request body. I don't want to send the random string. But I need to pass the random values from selected values. Ex; I have 5 values, say value1,value2,value3,value4,value5. I need to pass the random values among those five values. How can I do that? Any suggestions Please

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366723/random-product-selection-using-jmeter/22375601#22375601

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Easy way**

You can use [chooseRandom](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) function available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/)

**Hard way**

Use a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to get a random value as follows:

1. Add a Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of the request, which parameter you need to randomize
2. Put your `value1,value2,value3,value4,value5` into the PreProcessor's "Parameters" input
3. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   String[] params = Parameters.split(",");
   Random random = new Random();
   String randomValue = params[random.nextInt(params.length)];
   vars.put("randomValue", randomValue);
   ```
4. Refer generated value as `${randomValue}` where required.

See the following reference information for

1. Easy way: [Installing JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/)
2. Hard way: [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Comment: It is available in Standard Set so JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.2.0.zip should be enough. For current plugins version (1.2.0) direct URL is  http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.2.0.zip

Comment: Make sure that you **extracted** it in the root of your JMeter installation. Alternatively double-check that `JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar` file is present in /lib/ext folder. JMeter restart is required so JMeter could pick the plugins up. No more configuration needed, new functions are available at the same location where built-in functions are.

Comment: Use it in the request directly

Comment: Each time function is called it'll return a random value.

Comment: Exactly, but I need same value in both requests. So Is there any way to store the return value in user defined variables and use that variable in both requests.

Comment: The **last** argument is the mandatory variable which holds the result. I.e. if you populate the function as `${__chooseRandom(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,randomValue)}` result will be stored into `randomValue` variable which can be re-used in any number of samplers

Comment: I got some issue, Please give some suggestion, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153288/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-in-jmeter

Answer (score 4):

Say you have a variable `foo` and it can be `a` `b` or `c` and you want the sampler to select a random value from that set.

Create user-defined variables foo1=a foo2=b foo3=c

Then, use the following in your http request defaults:

`${__RandomFromMultipleVars(foo1|foo2|foo3)}`

and voila uniform random selection with no need for scripting or plugins

EDIT: if youre in to javascript, consider this one-liner:

`${__javaScript(Array("a"\, "b"\, "c")[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)])}`

^^that creates an array of three elements and returns a random element from within. No variables, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

how to pass the specific values not the random values, i.e for dynamic values how can we achieve this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).