# RSA encryption in JMeter

Tags: automation, jmeter

I have the issue explained here:

[javax.net.ssl.SSLException in jMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153288/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-in-jmeter)

The server tham I am testing is using RSA keys, so I should try third option from answer given in above question. But I don't know how to do this "change your client to only negotiate that." I am not writing my own code, and have no idea how to force Java or JMeter to handle this. I wanted to add a comment on question but, I still have no rights to post a comment, so I am posting another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link to very easy and complete solution.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you like first option from the linked answer?

1. Upgrade your Java to version 8 (you can get [Java 8 Server JRE from the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html))
2. Add the following line to *system.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
   ```

   Referenced `https.cipherSuites` property can be set in the system.properties file as well, just in case you will go for lowering the security way.

   Another option is passing the property via `-D` command line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -n -t yourtestplan.jmx -l results.jtl
   ```

   See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of working with them.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add comment on first option. I tried this, it seems that the bug is apparently not fixed in Java 8. I found on internet that some other people are also saying that bug is still present in Java 8 even if official it was said that bug is fixed. But I found solution:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html
I actually saw this thing before asking a question and I tried it few times, but I had many versions of java installed and I guess somehow I wan't placing these jars on right place or JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME were wrong.